# Parallel processing in ARIMA

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have one month half-hourly data (48 readings per day). Using `auto.arima()` of `R forecast` package, I forecast the readings of coming day. Currently, I forecast only for 5 days. Everything works fine, but issue is with running time

```
####### PARALLEL CASE ###########      
        library(doParallel); library(forecast)
Line 1  tsobject <- ts(data, frequency = 48)   
Line 2  arimaObject <- auto.arima(tsobject,xreg=temperature, stepwise = FALSE, parallel=TRUE,num.cores= detectCores-1) # temperature is another predictor variable
Line 3  predresult <- predict(arimaObject,n.ahead = 48, newxreg =   testday_data$temperature)
######### SERIAL CASE ###########
Line 2  arimaObject <- auto.arima(tsobject,xreg=temperature)
```

I used same code on two different machines and here are the running statistics

[image]

To me it seems that `parallel` option in `auto.arima()` is not working properly. Am I not able to use all the cores properly? Moreover, using the same data and same code, why it takes more time on ubuntu server as compared on MAC with 4 cores.

Comment: It would be better if you could compare running times with and without the `parallel` option on the *same* machine. Can you update your question with the info on the 40 core Ubuntu machine with `parallel=FALSE`? That said, your question is better suited for StackOverflow. I'll recommend migration, and you may want to flag the question and ask the moderator to migrate the question after you have edited this info into the question. Finally, if you don't get an answer at SO, you may want to contact the package maintainer, Rob Hyndman.

Comment: Have you registered the cores with registerDoParallel or similar function ?

Comment: @Jesus Herranz, No, I used only the `parallel` option of `auto.arima()`

Comment: There seems to be an error in your code. `detectCores()` is a function, not a variable, so you have to put `num.cores = detectCores()-1`. You are missing the parentheses. Also, I tried your code on my Windows machine with made up data; the cores were running.